# Devextreme list doesn't retain selected item

Tags: reactjs, devextreme-react

I have a simple react app with 2 components. On the left, there's a devExtreme list and on the right, there's a 'detail' pane. When I click an item in the list, I set a 'selectedItem' variable which is used by the right pane to show detail about this item. Now react rerenders - as it should - every time I change this variable (every time I click an item in the list). Now the list itself gets rerendered too so I lose the selection in the list. How should I tackle this problem? Thx
you can find the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/khz6h0?file=/src/App.js):

Comment: Please share your working code so far so help can be provided in context

Comment: I will create a code example!

Comment: you can find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/khz6h0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I found out that removing the line `searchExpr={["text"]}` resolves the problem, but why?